# How to make Expose filter of Author Id from autocomplete to select list?

Tags: 7, views

I added a exposed filter of `Author` and it showing me the autocomplete. How to change it in select list?

I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885759. Is there any other simple way to do it Because I have other filters also so I can't take a contextual filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom module with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517124 on the same post and solved my issue.